# How Can I Update a row SelectList with Multiple Selected Value

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a table named BookAuthors.

```
             BookAuthor
          Id | BookId | AuthorId
          1       1        1
          2       1        2
          3       2        1
```

I want to update a book ( By the bookId). I have a problem. I take the value from the database but I can't set selectlist's selectedvalue with multiple authors.

```
In the BookController class 

 public IActionResult Update(int Id)
        {
            var model = new BookViewModel
            {
                Book = _bookService.GetById(Id),
                Categories = _categoryService.GetListNotFirst(), // Get categories from the database
                Author = _authorService.GetListNotFirst(), // Get Authors from the database
                BookCategoriesList = _bookCategoryService.GetListByBookId(Id), //I get categories related to bookId. 
                BookAuthorsList = _bookAuthorService.GetListByBookId(Id) // I get authors related to bookId.
            };

            return View(model);
        }

In the BookViewModel 

   public class BookViewModel
    {
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<Author> Author { get; set; }
        public List<BookCategory> BookCategoriesList { get; set; }
        public List<BookAuthor> BookAuthorsList { get; set; }
        public string[] BookCategories { get; set; }
        public string[] BookAuthors { get; set; }
    }

Related part from the update view

 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookAuthors">Author Name</label>
                <select asp-for="BookAuthors" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Author, "Id", "Name",<selectedvalue>))" multiple> // Model.Author is a List<Author> property
                </select>
            </div>
```

I tried to this

```
select asp-for="BookAuthors" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Author, "Id", "Name",new[1,2] or new string["1,2"]))" multiple> 
                </select>
```

It didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide some more code about your controller.

Comment: @Akif I added the part about the controller above.

Comment: You need to use `MultiSelectList` instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.multiselectlist?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple items,you need to hold down the control (`ctrl`) button.You can refer to the `Usage Notes` of the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Here is a demo:

View(TestMulitipleList.cshtml):

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BookAuthors">Author Name</label>
        <select asp-for="BookAuthors" class="form-control" asp-items=@(new SelectList(Model.Author, "Id", "Name")) multiple >

        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestMulitipleList() {
            BookViewModel b = new BookViewModel
            {
                Author = new List<Author> {
                    new Author{  Id=1, Name="author1"},
                    new Author{  Id=2, Name="author2"},
                    new Author{  Id=3, Name="author3"},
                    new Author{  Id=4, Name="author4"},
                    new Author{  Id=5, Name="author5"},

                }
            };
            return View(b);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestMulitipleList(BookViewModel b)
        {
           
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

If you want to bind the selected value,you can do like this:

```
<select asp-for="BookAuthors" class="form-control" multiple>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Author)
            {
                if (item.Id == 1 || item.Id == 2)
                {
                    <option selected value=@item.Id>@item.Name</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value=@item.Id>@item.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: the problem here is he wants to ***initialize the selector with some selected items***. You have to render it manually or use `select` tag helper with `MultiSelectList`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the solution thanks to the comment above. If you want to select the categories of the book, there was a post saying 'Use multiselectlist' and I used it, it worked.